# Calculating values based off of values in other rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I'm trying to divide the value of one column based on whether there are multiple rows that meet the criteria. For this example all books have a 'Primary' author which will always receive the full point value. Books can also have one or multiple 'Secondary' authors, if a book has more than one Secondary author the points are divided equally between Secondary authors.

The desired output is to make the last column 'NewPoints'
Example:

Book 1 has a points value of 1 and only one secondary author, therefore the secondary author gets the full 1 point value.

Book 2 has a points value of 1 and has two secondary authors, therefore the secondary authors get a points value of 0.5 each.

Book 3 has a points value of 0.5 and has three secondary authors, therefore secondary authors get a points value of 0.16 each.

```
Select
b.BookID,
b.BookName,
bd.points,
a.AuthorName,
a.AuthorType,


From Book as b

LEFT JOIN bookdetails as bd
ON b.BookID = bd.BookID_FK

LEFT JOIN authors as a
ON bd.AuthorBookID = a.AuthorBookID
BookID | BookName      |Points|AuthorName   |Author Type | NewPoints

1      | Ocean's 11    |  1   | James Smith | Primary    |   1

1      | Ocean's 11    |  1   | Linus Key   | Secondary  |   1

2      | Number Two    |  1   | Jason Pitt  | Primary    |   1

2      | Number Two    |  1   | Will Franks | Secondary  |   0.5

2      | Number Two    |  1   | Donald Pe   | Secondary  |   0.5

3      | Cactus Jack   | 0.5  | Brad Saul   | Primary    |   0.5

3      | Cactus Jack   | 0.5  | Will Franks | Secondary  |   0.16

3      | Cactus Jack   | 0.5  | Linus Key   | Secondary  |   0.16

3      | Cactus Jack   | 0.5  | George Bray | Secondary  |   0.16
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only two types:

```
select b.BookID, b.BookName, bd.points, a.AuthorName, a.AuthorType,
       (case when bd.AuthorType = 'Primary' then bd.points
             else bd.points / count(*) over (partition by b.BookId, bd.AuthorType)
        end) as new_points
from Book b left join
     bookdetails as bd
     on b.BookID = bd.BookID_FK left join
     authors a
     on bd.AuthorBookID = a.AuthorBookID;
```

If you have more than two types and want to focus on `Secondary`, then:

```
       (case when bd.AuthorType = 'Primary'
             then bd.points
             when bd.AuthorType = 'Secondary'
             then bd.points / count(*) over (partition by b.BookId, bd.AuthorType)
        end) as new_points
```

Comment: Thanks mate that's exactly what I was after!